# Creating documents programmatically

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app that generates documents with each client's info based in a template, and that the client can sign. The signature is then jointed into the document, and the whole doc is converted to image and uploaded to a server.

Despite being converted to image, the objective is to be as similar as possible to the A4 format.

For this I use WebView, and then I convert it to Bitmap based on the width and height of an ScrollView.
For the signature I use Canvas.

But I'm not sure this approach is the best, as it is very difficult to simulate an A4 document. Depending on the device, the dimensions of the doc are not proportional and to be I would have to be adjusting based on each device display size. Because of that, this component of the app is not available in some devices, purposefully. But now we want to make it available to every device.

What approach do you recommend? Is there some way of develop one doc fits all with correct proportions and similar aspect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Maybe look into a library like [iTextPDF](https://github.com/itext/itext7) - a Java library for building custom PDF documents.

Answer (score 0):

Print to a PDF file. You can use Flying Saucer for that, or similar libraries.
PDF is famous for sticking to definitions and is especially fitted to the needs of proper scaling and displaying.

You could even get away from the doc template and only use (X)HTML to design and fill the page.
Simply fill in some HTML, link an image (`<img src='rel.jpg'>`), send all that to FlyingSaucer, and you're done.